# What sort of professional can I call for attic inspection and checking foundation?

Tags: attic, foundation, inspection

I am a single lady homeowner of a fix-up foreclosure. I bought the home for cash but did have a home inspection done. It has been almost 10 years, and although I did fix the things that were initially spotted I want to make sure everything is OK in a couple specific areas that I am really unfamiliar with: attic (enough insulation, look for plumbing leaks, dead birds, etc) and foundation (have cracks in walls & ceiling). I was considering whether getting another home inspection would be helpful, because they can look at all my major systems. Who to call - can I get a cheap analysis and estimate for any damages from just one person? Do I need a contractor or can a handyman type do the job?

Answer (score 1):

A home inspection would tell you WHAT's wrong. An architect would tell you WHAT's wrong, EVALUATE the conditions (i.e.: cracked foundation, lack of attic insulation, etc.) and offer SOLUTIONS on how to fix it, but not provide a bid...(but they could recommend several contractors to get bids from). A contractor would tell you WHAT's wrong, offer a SOLUTION and provide a bid to fix/repair the problem...but I'd recommend 3 reputable contractors and 3 bids.

Comment: I would add that foundation evaluation and repair may not be in the repertoire of "just any" contractor. You should seek a contractor with experience in that specifically.

Comment: That's great advice from both of you, thanks. I never like to "bother" a contractor unless absolutely necessary. Lee, you explained the options in a brilliant succinct way, thanks.

Comment: @MissT, please use upvotes and answer acceptance rather than "thank you" comments on SE.